# Clarification on Winapi Paths and Filename (W functions and A functions)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode, ascii

I have try to check an importance and reason to use W winapi vs A, (W meaning wide char, A meaning ascii right?)

I have made a simple example, i receive a temp path for current user like this:

```
CHAR pszUserTempPathA[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
WCHAR pwszUserTempPathW[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH - 1, pszUserTempPathA);

GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH - 1, pwszUserTempPathW);

printf("pathA=%s\r\npathW=%ws\r\n",pszUserTempPathA,pwszUserTempPathW);
```

My current user has a russian name, so its written in cyrillic, printf outputs like this:

```
pathA=C:\users\Пыщь\Local\Temp
pathW=C:\users\Пыщь\Local\Temp
```

So both paths are allright, i thought i will receive some error, or a mess of symbols with a `GetTempPathA` since the current user is a unicode, but i figured out, that cyrillic characters are actually included in extended ascii character set. So i have a question, if i were to use my software, and it will extract data in a temp folder of current user, who is chinese ( assuming he have chinese symbols in user name ), will i get a mess or an error using the `GetTempPathA` version? Should i always use a `W` prefixed functions, for a production software, that is working with winapi directly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Of course, you need the wide version. ASCII version can't even technically handle more than 256 distinct characters. Cyrillic is included in the extended ASCII set (if that's your localization) while Chinese isn't and can't due to much larger set of characters needed to represent it. Moreover, you can get mess with Cyrillic as well - it will only work properly if the executing machine has matching localization. So on a machine with non-cyrillic localization the text will be displayed according to whatever is defined by the localization settings.

Answer (score 7):

First, the -A suffix stands for ANSI, not ASCII.  ASCII is a 7-bit character set.  ANSI, as Microsoft uses the term, is for an encoding using 8-bit code units (`char`s) and code pages.

Some people use the terms "extended ASCII" or "high ASCII," but that's not actually a standard and, in some cases, isn't quite the same as ANSI.  Extended ASCII is the ASCII character set plus (at most) 128 additional characters.  For many ANSI code pages this is identical to extended ASCII, but some code pages accommodate variable length characters (which Microsoft calls multi-byte).  Some people consider "extended ASCII" to just mean ISO-Latin-1 (which is nearly identical to Windows-1252).

---

Anyway, with an ANSI function, your string can include any characters from your current code page.  **If you need characters that aren't part of your current code page, you're out-of-luck.  You'll have to use the wide -W versions.**

In modern versions of Windows, you can generally think of the -A functions as wrappers around the -W functions that use [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert any strings passing through the API.  But the latter conversion can be lossy, since wide character strings might include characters that your multibyte strings cannot represent.

---

Portable, cross-platform code often stores [all text in UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/), which uses 8-bit code units (`char`s) but can represent any Unicode code point, and anytime text needs to go through a Windows API, you'd explicitly convert to/from wide chars and then call the -W version of the API.

UTF-8 is nearly similar to what Microsoft calls a multibyte ANSI code page, except that Windows does not completely support a UTF-8 code page.  There is `CP_UTF8`, but it works only with certain APIs (like WideCharToMultiByte and MultiByteToWideChar).  You cannot set your code page to `CP_UTF8` and expect the general -A APIs to do the right thing.

---

As you try to test things, be aware that it's difficult (and sometimes impossible) to get the CMD console window to display characters outside the current code page.  If you want to display multi-script strings, you probably should write a GUI application and/or use the debugger to inspect the actual content of the strings.

Comment: Great except for the last part about the console. CMD is a shell that happens to use a console, which is a completely separate thing, just like an xterm and bash aren't the same. CMD uses the console's wide-character API as well as all wide-character WinAPI functions (e.g. `ReadConsoleW`, `WriteConsoleW`, `CreateProcessW`). It uses the console's output codepage only as something like POSIX `LANG`, for decoding the contents of batch files, reading from the pipe used in a `for /f` loop, and redirecting its internal commands (e.g. `dir`) to files or pipes (unless `cmd /u /c` is used).

Comment: The console itself stores the screen buffer as wide characters, but only one character per 'cell', so it can't properly display UTF-16 surrogate pairs beyond the basic multilingual plane. Such text can still be copied from the console and pasted elsewhere, however. That said, even for BMP text, displaying non-OEM text properly in the console does require that you select a TrueType font such as Consolas. Prior to Windows 8 it defaults to an OEM raster font. It also doesn't support complex scripts and fallback fonts (e.g. as DirectWrite enabled window would), so it leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: We typically run into trouble with legacy applications that use the C runtime default ANSI C locale. This ends up calling `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`, which ultimately does use the legacy console codepages (i.e. as returned by `GetConsoleCP` and `GetConsoleOutputCP`). Some people think switching to codepage 65001 (UTF-8) will solve the problem, but only because they haven't done extensive testing across supported versions of Windows (7+) and the C runtime to know how buggy it is. The only good solution is using the console's wide-character API, with explicit transcoding to UTF-8 if necessary.

Comment: I don't think any of that contradicts what I wrote.  The OP uses printf which boils down to ANSI style commands being sent to the console, so it's largely irrelevant that the console itself can work with wide characters.  No console-usable fixed-pitch TrueType font I know of on stock Windows covers both Cyrillic and CJK, which would necessary to handle the situation posited in the OP.  I'm just pointing out that using console-based experiments can really confuse the matter when you're trying to figure out how Windows APIs handle Unicode.

Comment: Primarily I wanted to clarify that what you said has nothing to do with CMD, and that CMD itself uses the console's wide-character API. A console application either inherits or allocates a console (whereas a GUI app has to manually allocate or attach to a console). CMD itself uses the Unicode API. A program could write out its results in a UTF-16 text file and then `type` it correctly in CMD. The text is at least in the console screen buffer correctly, even if the font's default character (e.g. empty box) is used. You can copy and paste it in another window that displays it correctly.

Comment: As to the OPs use of `printf` mixed with wide characters. I think that way is the path to madness. At startup, if stdout is a console, call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` and use `wprintf` instead. If you're writing a cross-platform app, consider creating wrapper functions that on Windows will decode UTF-8 to UTF-16LE and call wide-character functions. It's saner than managing the legacy codepage hell.

Comment: There are drawbacks to the `_setmode` and `wsprintf` approach, which are beyond the scope of this answer.  The point is, if you're trying to do some quick experiments, the console interface is likely to make it harder to understand what's going on.  And yes, CMD uses a console.  But if you're running your program in a CMD console rather than its own console, you can encounter additional surprises.

Comment: There's no such thing as a CMD console. If CMD is the parent process, a console application simply inherits CMD's console handle (the connection to the console host process, conhost.exe) and standard handles (by default these are for the console input and screen buffer), which CMD may have inherited from something else, such as powershell.exe or even a GUI program that called `AllocConsole`.

Comment: This isn't productive.  You've now written more words than I have in my answer, mostly about a topic that's tangential to the question.  If you feel this strongly about the console issue, propose an edit or submit your own answer.

Comment: You rightly brought up the OP's use of `printf` for interactive testing. This is part of the development process.  Using a console application is a simple and convenient tool here. I think you were too quick to write it off in favor of creating a GUI app. In many cases, the console is simply misunderstood. The suggestion to inspect with an attached debugger or IDE is good, as would be a more formal use of logging, but I still like the convenience of simple debug prints to the console. I often write little test programs in C, compiled and run directly on the command line.